# Pass a second argument to a function that takes first argument automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

A function `onChange` takes the only the first argument automatically (the ant design framework passes this automatic argument).

**Function call:** `this.onChange`

**Function declaration:**

```
onChange = (automatic_argument, my_argument) => {
  //my code
}
```

`my_argument` can be any one of the constants that I have defined depending on the calling context.

```
const LivingRoomOptions = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const DinningRoomOptions = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
const BedroomOptions = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
```

I want to pass these constants as the second argument to `onChange` function depending on from where it is called.

When I call the function like this `this.onChange(my_argument)`, it simply replaces the `automatic_argument`, which is obvious.

Calling `this.onChange(undefined, my_argument)`, simply injects undefined in place of `automatic_argument`.

How do pass `my_argument` to `onChange` without interfering with `automatic_argument`?

[antd link](http://ant.design/components/checkbox/)

Please refer to `checkall` section code in this link. Expand the code please.

Comment: Something like this onChange={event => this.onChange(event, my_argument)}.   Say ant design gives some value then onChange={ant_value => this.onChange(ant_value, my_argument)}

Comment: Can you swap the arguments?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal This automatic argument will get a string value of the check box label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically to pass multiple arguments to the handler function you should do like below.

```
 onChange={event => this.onChange(event, my_argument)}
```

To get the value or id of the element use `event.target` like

```
 onChange = (event, my_argument) => {
   console.log("value", event.target.value);
   console.log("id", event.target.id);
   //if it is checkbox then event.target.checked
   console.log("checked", event.target.checked);
 }
```

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma you didn't specify on which element you have onChange so I gave a hint on how to get the values in general. So as per ant design you will get values like I mentioned in updated answer. Please let me know if you still have queries

Comment: I still don't get how the solution that you gave works under the hood. Can you please, point me to a link or explain how it works.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma Here you go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 Arrow function syntax.

So lets say until now you did that:

```
<div onClick = {this.onChange} />
```

Now, try this:

```
<div onClick = {(automatic_argument) => 
this.onChange(automatic_argument,this.my_argument)} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest this.

```
onChange = (...args) => {
    //you have access to all arguments in an array.
}
```

The number of arguments passed does not matter